# Using multiple server_url for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, web, xmpp, server, google-cloud-messaging

Can I use more than one server URL for GCM xmpp implementation to reduce bandwidth and storage space load on one web server (domain)?

Like using one website for push as image other for video.

Example:  `public static final String SERVER_URL ="site1 /site2..."`or something else like this

After searching around, I'm stuck at this point as I can't find a cheaper way out.

Please point me in some direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to CCS, the URL of your server doesn't play any role. You can open up to 1000 connections to CCS with your credentials and it doesn't matter how many physical machines you will use for that.

Comment: Reedited the question.Please provide a solution on your thoughts about using multiple websites one for storing images other for video in the backend until device is offline to reduce storage and bandwidth  load on one website

Comment: @safedarma sorry, your question still makes no sense to me. How sending messages through GCM is related to storing images and videos?